# How do you give a row container the same width as a column container?

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

```css
.tip-container {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.tip {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: outset;
  min-height: 5em;
}

.tip-title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tip-content {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 .5em;
}

.tip-unaffordable,
.tip-link {
  line-height: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="tip-container">
  <div class="tip-1 tip">
    <div class="tip-title">Title</div>
    <div class="tip-content">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tip-2 tip">
    <div class="tip-link"><a tabindex="0" id="Link3">Tip<sup>3</sup></a></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tip-container column">
  <div class="tip-1 tip">
    <div class="tip-title">Title</div>
    <div class="tip-content">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tip-2 tip">
    <div class="tip-link"><a tabindex="0" id="Link3">Tip<sup>3</sup></a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/tietyt/pen/oNjbNVX

[image]

The only difference between these 2 containers is that one is using flex-direction of column. **How do I make both containers have exactly the same width?**  Also, why is this happening in the first place? Why don't they automatically line up?

Comment: box-sizing: border-box; to .tip elements (you have border + width:100%)

Comment: also note that both container have the same width but in the second one the element are overflowing ... in the first one the flex-shrink is preventing the overflow

Comment: @NishargShah I don't understand your question

Comment: @TemaniAfif `box-sizing: border-box;` was what i was looking for. Thank you for explaining that concept.

Comment: @DanielKaplan I happy for you, that you find your way.